# How to Disable comboBox if other comboBox is selected (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anyway to disable a combobox if a different combobox has some sort of text or value in it. I have tried a couple things and can't seem to get it to work.

Below is Example

[image: ComboBox]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the SelectedValueChanged event of combobox1 to check for the selected values. Disable or enable combobox2 based upon that.

```
private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    if (combobox1.SelectedValue == myDisableValue)
        combobox2.Enabled = false;
    else
        combobox2.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I used this, but I think I am going to add radio buttons and use                                                                 private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox4.Enabled = true;
            comboBox5.Enabled = false;
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx) event of both the combo boxes and if any of the combo has your required value disable the other one

Comment: so if (combobox1=="xxx") comboBox2 is locked?

Comment: or would you just recommend using radio Buttons?

Comment: if (combobox1.SelectedValue =="xxx") {comboBox2.Enabled = false;}

Comment: Depends on your scenario. It makes more sense to use Radio buttons if there will always be only one combo box with valid/useful value

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/04f92630-8c66-4e9d-8c95-22716d86177f

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this, only set whatever property you want, or don't clear it, or whatever. (test combos were not data bound)

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool fireEvents = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fireEvents) doCheck(sender, e);
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fireEvents) doCheck(sender, e);
    }

    private void doCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fireEvents = false; // because we don't have a way to cancel event bubbling
        if (sender == comboBox1)
        {
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else if (sender == comboBox2)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        fireEvents = true;
    }

}
```